# Filtering column based specific information by using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a problem for filtering my data. I stucked some point and cannot solve. I'using Pandas.

Let say I have more than two list. This time we can say im doing for three lists. These are: "A1","A2" and "A3".

A1=[x,m,d] A2=[dd,cc,aa,bb,tt], A3=[kk,yy,ll,ss]

For example my data is like that:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x,m,d | b |
| a | d | c |
| a | x,m,d,dd,cc | t |
| a | x,m,dd | k |
| a | yy,ll,dd,cc,aa | j |

Here, I want to extract whole column  in this list and if there is other character which belongs different list should be in new line. Like in the last row in data frame. Output should be like:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x,m,d | b |
| a | x,m,d | t |
| a | x,m | k |
| a | yy,ll | j |
| a | dd,cc,aa | j |

The second raw in the first data frame is gone because there is just one character. I want more than fifty percent of all character in list. And the last row in the first data frame is divided into two (they also obeying fifty percent rule).

*Fifty percent rule: For example for list A1 they are 3 and if there are 2 or more than two is ok for me or for A2 list there are for so 2 or more than 2 is ok.

I'm trying to do that but is there anyway to do it with pandas features? I couldn't do. If you help, that will be fine.
Thank you.

Comment: what if there are 2 elements found are they also going to break?

Comment: if there are two elements found, let say x and m just in the row which belong same list then there should be new row which include just x,m. Same logic but two or more than two. I edit the dataframes

Comment: Shouldn't the "z" column for rows 2 and 3 be t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Explanation:

1. Create columns that hold only the "special" and "other" characters from Column "y".
2. Keep only rows where the length of the special column is greater than 1.
3. Stack the "special" and "other columns" to get the new Column "y"

###### Code:

```
df["special"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: [char for char in x.split(", ") if char in special])
df["other"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: [char for char in x.split(", ") if char not in special])

output = df[df["special"].apply(len)>1]
output = output.drop("y", axis=1).set_index(["x", "z"]).stack().rename("y").reset_index().drop("level_2", axis=1)
output = output[output["y"].apply(len)>0][["x","y","z"]]
output["y"] = output["y"].apply(", ".join) #convert list back to string
```

###### Output:

```
>>> output
   x        y  z
0  a  x, m, d  b
2  a  x, m, d  t
3  a     g, i  t
4  a     x, m  k
5  a        i  k
```

###### Inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a", "a", "a", "a"],
                   "y": ["x, m, d", "d", "x, m, d, g, i", "x, m, i"],
                   "z": ["b", "c", "t", "k"]
                   })
special = ["x", "m", "d"]

>>> df
   x              y  z
0  a        x, m, d  b
1  a              d  c
2  a  x, m, d, g, i  t
3  a        x, m, i  k
```

#### Edit

Incorporating the 50% rule for multiple lists (after question was substantially changed)

###### Code:

```
df["A1"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: [char for char in x.split(", ") if char in A1])
df["A2"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: [char for char in x.split(", ") if char in A2])
df["A3"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: [char for char in x.split(", ") if char in A3])

output = df.drop("y", axis=1).set_index(["x", "z"]).stack().rename("y")
output = output[output.apply(lambda x: (all(c in A1 for c in x) and len(x)>=0.5*len(A1)) or
                                        (all(c in A2 for c in x) and len(x)>=0.5*len(A2)) or
                                        (all(c in A3 for c in x) and len(x)>=0.5*len(A3)))]
output.droplevel(2).reset_index()[["x", "y", "z"]]
```

###### Output:

```
>>> output
   x             y  z
0  a     [x, m, d]  b
1  a     [x, m, d]  t
2  a        [x, m]  k
3  a  [dd, cc, aa]  j
4  a      [yy, ll]  j
```

###### Inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a"],
                   "y": ["x, m, d", "d", "x, m, d, dd, cc", "x, m, dd", "yy, ll, dd, cc, aa"],
                   "z": ["b", "c", "t", "k", "j"]
                   })

A1 = ["x", "m", "d"]
A2 = ["dd", "cc", "aa", "bb", "tt"]
A3 = ["kk", "yy", "ll", "ss"]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error.  NameError: name 'special' is not defined

Comment: `special = ["x", "m", "d"]`. See the edited "Inputs"

Comment: sorry to ask again, here you defined two list "special" and "others". However my real data has three. so char in special or char not in special is not helping me. i know this is because of i didnt defined clearly but how can i do this with three different lists? Let say "A1" "A2" "A3"

Comment: That's very unclear - what are A1 A2 A3? Would you split rows when they exist in A1 or A2 or A3 or some other combination? This answer solves the *currently asked* question. You can either edit your question, or, for substantial changes, ask a new question.

Comment: I mean i wanna apply this more than one list instead of two (special and others). I referred "A1" "A2" A3" instead  of "special" and "others". I mean I don't need edit question because there is nothing to chance. I just wanted to apply this  more than two lists.

Comment: You need to ask a new question with appropriate examples. Let's say A1 =["x", "m", "d"], A2 = ["d", "g", "i"]. How would you split row 3 of your example?

Comment: Still makes no sense. Why is row 4 gone? It has x,m,dd, which is more than 50% of A1. Please post a new question. You have changed your original substantially.

Comment: yeah it obeying fifty percent and i write it as x,m but dd is belong A2 and there is just one. At least should be 3. So its gone